# Run Laravel docker image with exposing ports -p

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-run

I have a laravel app but I can't make it run with docker run command. The last two instructions are

```
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php", "artisan", "serve","--port=9000"]
```

I am trying to make it run trying with:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 my_image:latest
docker run --net="host" -p 9000:9000 my_image:latest
docker run --net="bridge" -p 9000:9000 my_image:latest
```

The only thing I see is the classic laravel output

```
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:9000>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is **127.0.0.1**:9000, i.e., the server is bound to localhost within the container, instead of listening on an external interface. The solution is to use the `--host 0.0.0.0` argument, which will bind the server to all available interfaces.

```
CMD ["php", "artisan", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port=9000"]
```